# How to match parentheses in Cucumber test

Tags: java, regex, cucumber, cucumber-junit

I currently have a problem with Java and Cucumber. Accessing a website's element by using Selenium, I want to use phrases like the following:

```
Then the value of the attribute XYZ should be 1000
```

That example is quite trivial and works fine for each attribute name by using the Java annotation

```
@Then("the value of the attribute (.*) should be (.*)")
```

except for the following use-case: an attribute name contains parentheses like `ABC(s)`.

While using Eclipse and JUnit, a Cucumber test with a string containing parentheses like that is not even recognized completely but just the part of the string before the opening bracket. Any ideas or solutions?

Comment: What seems to be the problem officer? http://regex101.com/r/iW3xS3

Comment: If you want to use special symbols in your regex, are you escaping them out appropriately? e.g. for `(` you need to write `\\(`

Comment: Well, it's definitely not the regex itself what causes the problem. Cucumber just finds `Then the value of the attribute XYZ` instead of `Then the value of the attribute XYZ(s) should be 1000` when I run a JUnit-Test

Comment: @Peter Lawrey nope, it doesn't work either.

Comment: Having `(` or `)` in the input shouldn't make any difference. AFAIK Cucumber uses standard regex which doesn't care about such things.

Comment: A phrase containing parentheses is simply cut of at the first parenthesis' position.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't matter whether the attribute name contains any parentheses.

When using this method:

```
@Then("^the value of the attribute (.*) should be (.*)$")
public void checkAttributeValue(String name, String value)
        throws Throwable {
    System.out.println("Name: " + name + " value: " + value);
}
```

And

```
Then the value of the attribute XYZ(s) should be 1000
```

I get

```
Name: XYZ(s) value: 1000
```

Which I think is what you expect.

Comment: Okay, it turned out that only Eclipse's JUnit-View doesn't print the test-cases correctly. For example for the case

`Then the value of the attribute XYZ(s) should be 1000`

the following is printed:

`Then the value of the attribute XYZ`.